# Let A1, A2,...,An be sets. Prove that if A1 is a subset of A2, A2 a subset of A3, ..., An subset of A1, then A1=A2=...=An

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help with the proof of an elementary set theory question. I believe my proof is not rigorous enough.

The statement is: Let $A_1$, $A_2$, ..., $A_n$ be sets. Prove that if $A_1\subset A_2$, $A_2\subset A_3$ ,..., $A_{n-1}\subset A_n$  and $A_n\subset A_1$ , then $A_1=A_2=...=A_n$

Attempt at Proof:
Since $A_1\subset A_2$, for every $x\in A_1$, $x \in A_2$. Further since $A_2\subset A_3$, for $x\in A_2$, $x \in A_3$. Continuing the same logic, we would finally have for $x\in A_n$, $x \in A_1$. Thus we showed that $A_2\subset A_1$ , which implies $A_1 = A_2$. Similarly, we would have $A_2 = A_3 = ...= A_n = A_1$ which we had set out to prove.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: It looks good. I think its fine.

Comment: Your proof need not consider elements $x$, it's a distraction. M.A. 's answer is tighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that,

> $A=B$ if and only if $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$.

Now, $A_1\subset A_n$ and $A_n\subset A_1$ therefore $A_1=A_n$.

$A_2\subset A_n$ and $A_n\subset A_1\subset A_2$, hence $A_2=A_n$ and $A_1=A_2=A_n$.